# How to gain authorization in POST requests in Spring boot instead of having 401 unauthorized access?

Tags: spring-boot, post, authorization, csrf-token, spring-boot-security

All my `GET` requests works fine with authorized access but, all my `POST` requests are returned with 401 unauthorized access and I am using Basic authorization with username and password, I guess the problem is emerging from CSRF token but I have disabled and nothing happens.

Below is my `SecurityConfig` class

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                //.cors(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .csrf((csrf) -> csrf.disable())
                .authorizeHttpRequests((authz) -> authz
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/**").permitAll()
                        //.requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/**").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults());

        return http.build();

    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService users() {
        // The builder will ensure the passwords are encoded before saving in memory
        //User.UserBuilder users = User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder();
        UserDetails user = User.builder()
                .username("user")
                .password(passwordEncoder().encode("pass"))
                .roles("USER")
                .build();
        UserDetails admin = User.builder()
                .username("admin")
                .password(passwordEncoder().encode("admin"))
                .roles("USER", "ADMIN")
                .build();
        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user, admin);
    }


}
```

and this is my controller

```
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole(ADMIN)")
    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<PostDto> createPost(@Valid @RequestBody PostDto postDto) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(postService.createPost(postDto), HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
```

and these are my logs

```
2023-09-10T23:55:35.850+02:00 DEBUG 20476 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter         : Invalid CSRF token found for http://localhost:8080/api/posts
2023-09-10T23:55:35.850+02:00 DEBUG 20476 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.s.w.access.AccessDeniedHandlerImpl   : Responding with 403 status code
2023-09-10T23:55:35.851+02:00 DEBUG 20476 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing POST /error
2023-09-10T23:55:35.851+02:00 DEBUG 20476 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
2023-09-10T23:55:35.852+02:00 DEBUG 20476 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] s.w.a.DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint : Trying to match using And [Not [RequestHeaderRequestMatcher [expectedHeaderName=X-Requested-With, expectedHeaderValue=XMLHttpRequest]], MediaTypeRequestMatcher [contentNegotiationStrategy=org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManager@379dbd63, matchingMediaTypes=[application/xhtml+xml, image/*, text/html, text/plain], useEquals=false, ignoredMediaTypes=[*/*]]]
2023-09-10T23:55:35.852+02:00 DEBUG 20476 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] s.w.a.DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint : Trying to match using Or [RequestHeaderRequestMatcher [expectedHeaderName=X-Requested-With, expectedHeaderValue=XMLHttpRequest], And [Not [MediaTypeRequestMatcher [contentNegotiationStrategy=org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManager@379dbd63, matchingMediaTypes=[text/html], useEquals=false, ignoredMediaTypes=[]]], MediaTypeRequestMatcher [contentNegotiationStrategy=org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManager@379dbd63, matchingMediaTypes=[application/atom+xml, application/x-www-form-urlencoded, application/json, application/octet-stream, application/xml, multipart/form-data, text/xml], useEquals=false, ignoredMediaTypes=[*/*]]], MediaTypeRequestMatcher [contentNegotiationStrategy=org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManager@379dbd63, matchingMediaTypes=[*/*], useEquals=true, ignoredMediaTypes=[]]]
2023-09-10T23:55:35.852+02:00 DEBUG 20476 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] s.w.a.DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint : Match found! Executing org.springframework.security.web.authentication.DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint@7ca4ed9f
2023-09-10T23:55:35.852+02:00 DEBUG 20476 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] s.w.a.DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint : Trying to match using RequestHeaderRequestMatcher [expectedHeaderName=X-Requested-With, expectedHeaderValue=XMLHttpRequest]
2023-09-10T23:55:35.853+02:00 DEBUG 20476 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] s.w.a.DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint : No match found. Using default entry point org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint@74626aab
```

Spring boot v3.1.2

If someone can help, I'd appreciate.

Comment: Your question is confusing me, you mention POST requests not working, but you're showing the PUT method in your controller and you have commented out the 
`.requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/**").permitAll()` in your security configuration. Perhaps that's one of your errors?

Comment: Sry for this confusion, I have edited the correct controller method, and about commenting this line I have tried executing it before and it doesn't resolve the problem @voidvoid

Comment: Can you add the `@Bean` annotation above your `public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http)` function. I believe your configuration is not being picked up at all.

Comment: It worked!! after adding @Bean annotation, thank you! if you can please tell me why this was so important and if it is should I add it in every single method in Spring boot or what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply defining the method in your configuration class is not enough. Spring security has a default security filter chain, and if you want to override some behavior you have to provide your own bean.

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) { ... }
```

The `@Bean` annotation is necessary because you want to communicate "here, use this method to create a SecurityFilterChain bean". Once the bean is present in the context, it will be automatically picked up.

To answer your question "should I add it in every single method in Spring boot or what?":
No, you should not. You add it when you want to specify that your method returns a bean to be managed by the spring context. Often you will be configuring some aspect of spring using this method, but in general your methods don't return beans.